# $f(u)$ has twice continuous Derivative in $[1,+\infty),f(1)=-1,f'(1)=3/2,w=(x^2+y^2+z^2)f(x^2+y^2+z^2)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

$f(u)$ has twice continuous derivative in $[1,+\infty)$, $$f(1)=-1,\ f'(1)=3/2,\ w=(x^2+y^2+z^2)f(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$such that $$\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial z^2}=0$$

find the minimum of $f(u)$ in  $[1,+\infty)$.

My try:
I pretend that $r=x^2+y^2+z^2$ ,so that I can replace $w$ to $rf(r)$.Then I substituted it into  $\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial z^2}$=0 ,getting $(8r^2+6r)f'(r)+4r^3f''(r)+6f(r)=0.$ I don't know how to solve or if there are any simple ways.what should I do next?

Comment: Can somebody answer me?

Comment: I seems that the $f'$ should be accompanied by $8r+6$ and $f''$ by $r^2$. You can try to solve that equation explicitly by a substitution $u = \log r$ or something similar.

Comment: Also, do you know anything about harmonic functions and their minima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure the differential equation you obtain is correct. I'll provide a solution to the corrected differential equation, but perhaps some nicer argument with harmonic functions avoids computations.

If $r$ is as you wrote, and if we let $F = f(r)$, then

$$\partial_x r = 2x,\quad \partial_x^2 r = 2,\quad \partial_x F = f'(r)2x,\quad \partial_x^2 F=f''(r)4x^2 + 2f'(r)$$

Putting this together gives $$\partial_x^2(r f(r)) = 2 f(r) + 2 \cdot 2x f'(r) \cdot 2x + r (f''(r)4x^2+2f'(r))$$

and adding the other two variables to get $\Delta= \partial_x^2+\partial_y^2+\partial_z^2$ gives
$$\Delta (rf(r)) = 6f(r) + 8r f'(r) + r(f''(r)4r+6f'(r))$$

i.e. $6 f(r)+(8r+6) f'(r) + 4r^2 f''(r) = 0$. This is quite nice because it is more or less an Euler--Cauchy equation. In fact, let $g(r) = r f(r)$. Then the equation reads

$$4rg''(r) + 6g'(r) = 0$$

which is an Euler--Cauchy equation. You obtain $g' = \lambda r^{-3/2}$ so that

$$g(r) - g(1) = \lambda \int_1^r s^{-3/2}ds = \lambda ( 2-2r^{-1/2})$$

Now $g(1) = f(1) = -1$ so $f(r) = \left( r^{-1}+\lambda ( 2r^{-1}-2r^{-3/2})\right)$. To pin down $\lambda$ it suffices you use the condition on $f'(1)$.